# Troubles configuring second interface on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu

I'm trying to setup my home server with two connections but I'm hitting a bit of a wall that I can't seem to climb while configuring my interfaces.

This is on Ubuntu 16.04 if that matters. 
I have one onboard NIC and one PCI-E NIC. They are called enp10s0 and enp3s0.

/etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp10s0
iface enp10s0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.170
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
    gateway 192.168.0.1

auto enp3s0
iface enp3s0 inet static
    address 192.168.178.22
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

/etc/iproute2/rt_tables

```
#
# reserved values
#
255     local
254     main
253     default
0       unspec
#
# local
#
#1      inr.ruhep
21 enp3s0
```

The rules I made for this table:

```
# Create route table 
ip route add 192.168.178.0/24 dev enp3s0 table 21
ip route add default via 192.168.178.1 dev enp3s0 table 21
```

ip route show:

```
default via 192.168.0.1 dev enp10s0 onlink
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp3s0  scope link  metric 1000
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
172.19.0.0/16 dev br-d5225db5076a  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.19.0.1 linkdown
192.168.0.0/24 dev enp10s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.170
192.168.178.0/24 dev enp3s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.178.22
```

The second and third one are for Docker but I assume those aren't important.

Now when I ping from the default interface `enp10s0` everything works fine, however when I try to ping from the second interface `enp3s0` I get

```
ping -I enp3s0 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) from 192.168.178.22 enp3s0: 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.178.22 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.178.22 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.178.22 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
```

Now unfortunately my network knowledge isn't as large as I would like it to be so I can't figure this one out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Output of `ip rule`?  As in do you have rules in place to tell your system to use the second table?

Comment: Yeah my bad, I forgot to list that one:
   
   ```ip rule add priority 1000 fwmark 21 table 21```

Comment: ```999: from 192.168.178.0/24 lookup enp3s0 ``` The one in my previous comment is for routing all packets from a certain user to this interface, so I guess that's not relevant (and missing the ip tables commands to mark these packets, but that part of my script works so that's fine)

Comment: And you have no other ip rules?  How is that rule 999  supposed to forcing packets to use the alternate table?  Don't you need to tell it which  table to use?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the firewall on the second host 192.168.178.1 is not the same as the configured gateway 192.168.0.1 // .

When using iptables make sure that you configure input, output, as well as pass-through traffic.

When you reboot what happens?
Did you try ifdown && ifup?

Try configuring from the start and follow the guidelines for setting up the interfaces.
All that needs to be done is the DHCP enabled on the interface.

When the hardware is added to the computer, and when you can assign a hardware address, you will get the name value for that address.. like en0 or eth1.
Assign localhost and add the interface to the loopback device. For instance in /etc/hosts add the line to tie the interface to the loopback. i.e. 127.0.1.1 .

When all is working correct allow to actually receive traffic. Check Ubuntu Firewall.

$ sudo ufw status
$ sudo ufw disable

Only use this option to test. Later use 'ufw enable' to verify the firewall is not blocking the traffic. On either this host, or the host routed to, is in another network. So the broadcast mask for the subnet ID, it must be 255.255.0.0, because it is in a domain with 255 x 255 servers, +1.

The routed host 192.168.178.1 will receive the traffic. In its firewall ICMP, ICMP_REPLY must be allowed, as well your host configured to be allowed for a bounce.

Also the ICMP packet must have a TTL value.